# If statement in django template

Tags: django, templates, if-statement

I have a if statement to test if the categorie of the file is audio and I want to show the html audio tag if it is true.

I tried to remove the if statement juste to test the audio tag and it is working just fine.

Now the code is working, thanks to Sammy J, I updated the template code with the good one :

```
<p class="blog-post-meta">Publié le {{ medias.uploaded_media|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" }} dans la catégorie {{ medias.categorie_media | title }}</p>

    <p>{{ medias.description_media | linebreaks }}</p>

 {% if medias.categorie_media.nom_categorie == 'Audio' %}
    <audio controls src="{{medias.fichier_media.url}}">Votre navigateur ne supporte pas la lecture audio, veuillez télécharger le fichier.</audio>
 {% endif %}

    <p><a href="{{medias.fichier_media.url }}" target="_blank">Cliquez ici pour télécharger le fichier</a></p>
```

The view :

```
def medias_detail(request, id):
    try:
        medias = Media.objects.get(id=id)
    except Media.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    template_name = 'medias_detail.html'
    context = {
        "medias" : medias
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

The model :

```
class Media(models.Model):
    nom_media = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    fichier_media = models.FileField()
    uploaded_media = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    categorie_media = models.ForeignKey('MediaCat',
                                       on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                       default='1') 
    description_media = models.TextField(default='Description du fichier')
```

Comment: can you ad more info to the question, like the view from which you are trying to render this page and the model also

Comment: Hi Sammy J, Yep will do :)

Comment: can you add your model as well ?

Comment: Hello Nalin, it's done :)

Comment: can you check the value of variable in template- {{ medias.categorie_media }} ?

Comment: Hello Mohit, yes I checked the value and it's Audio :) I know it because I call it somewhere else in the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the model posted by you I see that the `categorie_media` is a foreign key, which means you cant compare directly in the template like `{% if medias.categorie_media == "Audio" %}`, since it stores foreign keys

So, you must give whatever field is in the other model `MediaCat`(since it isn't posted in the question) that stores the value `Audio` as a string to compare.

e.g `{% if medias.categorie_media.<other_field_from_MediaCat> == "Audio" %}`

If this does not solve your issue, please do post your `MediaCat` model.

Answer (score 0):

There are not enough informations, but the code itself seems to be correct.

Is "medias" a collection (eg. list), because it's a plural noun?
If yes, you need to put it into a for loop.

```
{% for media in medias %}
{% if media.categorie_media == "Audio" %}
<audio controls src="{{media.fichier_media.url}}">Votre navigateur ne supporte pas la lecture audio, veuillez télécharger le fichier.</audio>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

In the description of the problem you write "audio" as lower case. If this is correct, {% if media.categorie_media == "Audio" %} will of course be False.

Comment: Hi Frank, no medias is not a list. The view return only one entry from the database get by the id. By audio I mean the html audio tag, the categorie name has a caps A ^^

Comment: Can you add {{ medias }} - 
{{ medias.categorie_media }} - 
{{ medias.fichier_media.url }} somewhere to show the current values at this point? Most likely the if statement remains false i think.

Comment: Already done and the value of medias.categorie_media is Audio